# Check Layout of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

I Have the following code piece:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

I would like to check, if my panel has a `GridBagLayout` assigned to it.
I got it working like this:

```
if(panel.getLayout().getClass() == GridBagLayout.class) {
   // seems to work
}
```

Although it works, its kind of hacky since I dont want to use reflection for this.

**Is there another way to check the assigned layout?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `instanceof` statement Luke

```
if(panel.getLayout() instanceof GridBagLayout) {
    // seems to work
}
```

Comment: Absolutely right I just noticed this by myself.. Thanks :)

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt a little hint: if you check my answer as helpful, you'll get 2 points of reputation. ;)

Comment: thats what I always do, but you have to wait a couple minutes after a question was asked to mark an answer as correct :)

Comment: be aware that this will also return `true` for sub-classes of `GridBagLayout`, which is not the case of questions code (IMO this answer is the better/correct way to do it, just a note for some reader using that for something else, where eventually class must match exactly)